# Merging two arrays of dictionaries based on a shared value

Tags: swift

Let's say I have two arrays of dictionaries:

```
[["id":"1","color":"orange"],["id":"2","color":"red"]]
```

and

```
[["id":"1","fruit":"pumpkin"],["id":"2","fruit":"strawberry"]]
```

How can I merge these based on "id" so that I get

```
[["id":"1","color":"orange","fruit":"pumpkin"],["id":"2","color":"red","fruit":"strawberry"]]
```

We know that the two arrays will be the same length. We don't know if the two arrays will be in the same order.

What's the best way to merge each dictionary in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

The Swift Standard Library in Xcode 9 introduces `merge`.

The code filters the corresponding dictionary of `array2` with the same `id` and merges the keys and values into `array1`:

```
var array1 = [["id":"1","color":"orange"], ["id":"2","color":"red"]]
var array2 = [["id":"1","fruit":"pumpkin"], ["id":"2","fruit":"strawberry"]]

for (index, item) in array1.enumerated() {
    if let filtered = array2.first(where: {$0["id"]! == item["id"]! }) {
        array1[index].merge(filtered) { (current, _) in current }
    }
}

print(array1)
```

I don't know if `merge` is available in Swift 3.2, too

Comment: merge is only available since Swift 4 Xcode 9 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919536-merge

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I'm going to assume that the first `Array` is mutable:

```
var xs = [["id": "1", "color": "orange"], ["id": "2", "color": "red"]]
let ys = [["id": "1", "fruit": "pumpkin"], ["id": "2", "fruit": "strawberry"]]

for x in xs.enumerated() {
  for y in ys {
    if x.element["id"] == y["id"] {
      for (key, value) in y {
        if x.element[key] == nil {
          xs[x.offset][key] = value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4's new Dictionary initializers will let you do some pretty impressive magic including merging such as this:

```
let a1 = [["id":"1","color":"orange"],["id":"2","color":"red"]]
let a2 = [["id":"1","fruit":"pumpkin"],["id":"2","fruit":"strawberry"]]

let merged = Dictionary((a1+a2).map{($0["id"]!,Array($0))}){$0 + $1}
             .map{Dictionary($1 as [(String,String)]){$1}}

print(merged)
// [["id": "2", "fruit": "strawberry", "color": "red"], ["id": "1", "fruit": "pumpkin", "color": "orange"]]
```