# Swift 3 - Compare key values from two different dictionaries and update one of them if key value matches

Tags: swift, dictionary, compare, key-value

I have two arrays of dictionaries:

```
Dict 1 = 
[{"id":"100", "name":"Matt", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}
,{"id":"110", "name":"Sean", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}
, {"id":"120", "name":"Luke", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}]

Dict 2 = 
[{"id":"100", "address":"1 Main Street"}
,{"id":"110", "address":"2 Main Road"}
, {"id":"120", "address":"3 Main Street"}]
```

I want to compare the key:value pair, ***id*** ,  of each dictionary in Dict 2 against Dict 1, and if the id matches, update the corresponding address in Dict 1 from the value in Dict2.

So the **desired output** should be:

```
Dict 1 = 
[{"id":"100", "name":"Matt", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"1 Main Street"}
,{"id":"110", "name":"Sean", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"2 Main Road"}
, {"id":"120", "name":"Luke", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"3 Main Street"}]
```

**EDIT**

As requested, here is more information regarding how I am parsing the data. I am getting Dict1 and Dict2 as response to HTTP URL call btw. And also, I use dictionaries of the type [Dictionary] while parsing.

```
        let Task1 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL!) { (Data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let DataContent = Data {
                    do {
                        let JSONresponse1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: DataContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                        print(JSONresponse1)

                        for item in JSONresponse1 as! [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                            //Parse here    
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.getAddressTask()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        Task1.resume()
    }
```

JSONResponse1 is Dict 1

Then inside the getAddressTask() func called above, I do the HTTP URL call to get Dict 2

```
    let AddressTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL2!) { (Data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let DataContent = Data {
                do {
                    let JSONresponse2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: timeRestrictionsDataContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                    print(JSONresponse2)
                        for item in JSONresponse2 as! [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                            //Parse here    
                        }
                catch { }
                self.compileDictionaries()
            }
        }
    }
    AddressTask.resume()
```

JSONResponse2 is Dict2

Inside compileDictionaries() i would like to get the **desired output as shown above.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two arrays of dictionaries based on a shared value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570988/merging-two-arrays-of-dictionaries-based-on-a-shared-value)

Comment: You don't have two dictionaries. You have two array of dictionaries

Comment: Leo that’s what I mentioned in the first line. But it will be a comparison of each dictionary within those arrays.

Comment: I suggest you struct your data using Codable protocol instead of working with dictionaries

Comment: What you have is two json strings. Btw you should show what you have tries and the issues you are facing

Comment: As @LeoDabus has said, you do not have valid Swift code in your question.  Those are JSON strings representing arrays of dictionaries. Either show how you are parsing the JSON or convert the JSON to Swift in order to have a better example.

Comment: @LeoDabus and I have added info on how I am getting the JSON data. I get Dict1 and Dict2 as a responses to two HTTP URL requests. What do you suggest after seeing this? :)

Comment: @ColGraff tagging you as I couldnt tag you in the previous comment.

Comment: Please help guys. I'm very new to swift.

Comment: note that Data is a Swift native type and it is Swift convention to name your vars starting with a lowercase letter. You should change `(Data, response, error)` to `data, response, error` and `if let DataContent = Data {` to  `if let data = data {`, and `if let dictionaries = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {`

Answer (score 1):

You should struct your data using Codable protocol and create a mutating method to update your contact. If you need an array of your contacts once you have them updated all you need is to encode your contacts using JSONEncoder:

```
struct Contact: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: String
    var address: String?
    var name: String?
    var phone: String?
    mutating func update(with contact: Contact) {
        address = contact.address ?? address
        name = contact.name ?? name
        phone = contact.phone ?? phone
    }
    var description: String {
        return "ID: \(id)\nName: \(name ?? "")\nPhone: \(phone ?? "")\nAddress: \(address ?? "")\n"
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let json1 = """
[{"id":"100", "name":"Matt", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"},
{"id":"110", "name":"Sean", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"},
{"id":"120", "name":"Luke", "phone":"0404040404", "address":"TBC"}]
"""

let json2 = """
[{"id":"100", "address":"1 Main Street"},
{"id":"110", "address":"2 Main Road"},
{"id":"120", "address":"3 Main Street"}]
"""

var contacts: [Contact] = []
var updates: [Contact] = []
do {
    contacts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Contact].self, from: Data(json1.utf8))
    updates = try JSONDecoder().decode([Contact].self, from: Data(json2.utf8))
    for contact in updates {
        if let index = contacts.index(where: {$0.id == contact.id}) {
            contacts[index].update(with: contact)
        } else {
            contacts.append(contact)
        }
    }
    let updatedJSON = try JSONEncoder().encode(contacts)
    print(String(data: updatedJSON, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will print:

> [{"id":"100","phone":"0404040404","name":"Matt","address":"1 Main
>   Street"},{"id":"110","phone":"0404040404","name":"Sean","address":"2
>   Main
>   Road"},{"id":"120","phone":"0404040404","name":"Luke","address":"3
>   Main Street"}]

Comment: I like the `if let index = contacts.index(where: {$0.id == contact.id})` bit of code, I certainly don't use that method near enough.

Comment: I would also make the contact equatable but I think I will leave that assignment to the OP

Comment: Yeah, best to keep the answer simple. It's already a bit more than the OP asked for, though it certainly shows some good practices.